# how can I access files from s3 bucket in my ec2 instance

Tags: java

I am having my war files in the s3 bucket and I needs a means to download this file into my ec2 instance , this has to be done automatically through programme using AWS sdk. advice me.

Comment: You'll get more helpful answers if you explain a little more what you've tried, and where you got stuck. E.g. have you looked at the docs, is there something particular that is confusing or doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: hi Edc.. I want my app to be run on ec2 this should be done programmatically using aws sdk.I have looked at the docs. but getting the complete picture. I want to attach ebs volume to ec2. Already I have a war file store in s3. i want to store the war from s3 to ebs, all should be done programatically. plz advice me.